# Phaser box2d touch drag

Tags: javascript, box2d, phaser-framework

Good day.
Is there a way to make touch dragging in Phaser+box2d?
All the examples I see use

```
game.input.onDown.add(mouseDragStart, this);
game.input.addMoveCallback(mouseDragMove, this);
game.input.onUp.add(mouseDragEnd, this);

function mouseDragStart()
game.physics.box2d.mouseDragStart(game.input.
}

function mouseDragMove()
game.physics.box2d.mouseDragMove(game.input.mousePointer)
}

function mouseDragEnd()
game.physics.box2d.mouseDragEnd();
}
```

But this only works with mouse, so no touch support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, and it's very easy :)

In your code you have `game.input.mousePointer`. Switch this over to `game.input.activePointer`.

```
function create() {
    // ...

    // nothing needs to change here.
    game.input.onDown.add(mouseDragStart, this);
    game.input.addMoveCallback(mouseDragMove, this);
    game.input.onUp.add(mouseDragEnd, this);

    // ...
}

function mouseDragStart() {
    game.physics.box2d.mouseDragStart(game.input.activePointer);
}

function mouseDragMove() {
    game.physics.box2d.mouseDragMove(game.input.activePointer);
}
```

The `mouseDragEnd()` function can stay as-is.